# gparted gives an error when checking the xfs file system

Tags: gparted, tmp, umount, xfs

I use ubuntu 16.04 (64). An additional, non-system drive is formatted in XFS. After a power failure, I decided to check it. Gparted report:

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
Libparted 3.2
Check and repair file system (xfs) on /dev/sdd1  00:00:19    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sdd1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdd1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 3907028991
size: 3907026944 (1.82 TiB)
check file system on /dev/sdd1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:19    ( SUCCESS )

xfs_repair -v /dev/sdd1  00:00:19    ( SUCCESS )

Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
- block cache size set to 1397872 entries
Phase 2 - using internal log
- zero log...
zero_log: head block 837056 tail block 837056
- scan filesystem freespace and inode maps...
- found root inode chunk
Phase 3 - for each AG...
- scan and clear agi unlinked lists...
- process known inodes and perform inode discovery...
- agno = 0
- agno = 1
- agno = 2
- agno = 3
- process newly discovered inodes...
Phase 4 - check for duplicate blocks...
- setting up duplicate extent list...
- check for inodes claiming duplicate blocks...
- agno = 0
- agno = 1
- agno = 2
- agno = 3
Phase 5 - rebuild AG headers and trees...
- agno = 0
- agno = 1
- agno = 2
- agno = 3
- reset superblock...
Phase 6 - check inode connectivity...
- resetting contents of realtime bitmap and summary inodes
- traversing filesystem ...
- agno = 0
- agno = 1
- agno = 2
- agno = 3
- traversal finished ...
- moving disconnected inodes to lost+found ...
Phase 7 - verify and correct link counts...

XFS_REPAIR Summary Mon May 21 07:32:22 2018

Phase Start End Duration
Phase 1: 05/21 07:32:03 05/21 07:32:03
Phase 2: 05/21 07:32:03 05/21 07:32:03
Phase 3: 05/21 07:32:03 05/21 07:32:13 10 seconds
Phase 4: 05/21 07:32:13 05/21 07:32:13
Phase 5: 05/21 07:32:13 05/21 07:32:13
Phase 6: 05/21 07:32:13 05/21 07:32:21 8 seconds
Phase 7: 05/21 07:32:21 05/21 07:32:21

Total run time: 18 seconds
done
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

mkdir -v /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

Created directory /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF
mount -v -t xfs /dev/sdd1 /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

mount: /dev/sdd1 mounted on /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF.
xfs_growfs /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

meta-data=/dev/sdd1 isize=512 agcount=4, agsize=122094592 blks
= sectsz=4096 attr=2, projid32bit=1
= crc=1 finobt=1 spinodes=0
data = bsize=4096 blocks=488378368, imaxpct=5
= sunit=0 swidth=0 blks
naming =version 2 bsize=4096 ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log =internal bsize=4096 blocks=238466, version=2
= sectsz=4096 sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none extsz=4096 blocks=0, rtextents=0
umount -v /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

umount: /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF: target is busy
(In some cases useful info about processes that
use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
rmdir -v /tmp/gparted-zL4DeF  00:00:00    ( N/A )

rmdir(/tmp/gparted-zL4DeF): Device or resource busy
```

Why this error occurs and how to correct it?

P.S. I'm not very experienced in repairing file systems and do not fully understand the report. Please tell me if the files are damaged?